# Display by ObjectProperty in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I have a problem in displaying the result using SPARQL in protege.
I have two classes Panne and Solution and an ObjectProperty hasSolution .
I want to display the Panne that has A Solution ex: GODEX hasSolution SOLGODEX.
I tried

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX panne:<http://www.semanticweb.org/rahma/ontologies/2020/pannesOnto.owl#>

SELECT ?Panne ?Solution
WHERE {
?Panne panne:hasSolution ?Solution}
```

Comment: what does not work with your query? And do you have instances that are connected via the property `panne:hasSolution`?

Answer (score 0):

*Without knowing your specific ontology structure, the following will likely need some adaptations.*

Currently your query selects all subjects and objects involved in a tuple using `panne:hasSolution`.

If you want to filter down to only those of a specific solution, you have to include that in the query:

```
SELECT ?Panne
WHERE {
  ?Panne panne:hasSolution ex:SOLGODEX .
}
```

If you want all pairs of `panne:Panne` and `panne:Solution`, add the respective patterns to select only members ot those classes:

```
SELECT ?Panne ?Solution
WHERE {
  ?Panne a panne:Panne .
  ?Solution a panne:Solution .
  ?Panne panne:hasSolution ?Solution .
}
```